# Stopping Google from crawling my static domain

Tags: seo, google-search, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I use a cookieless sub domain `static.example.com` to serve all images, js, and css files. This static sub domain has as its root directory the same directory as the parent `http://example.com`. So `static.example.com/index.php` will result in calling the same file as `http://example.com/index.php`

Google has taken up indexing `static.example.com` and I need to stop this.

I can't modify robots.txt since it would apply to both domains.
Webmaster tools allows "temporary" removal of a link, but this needs to be permanent.

I registered this static domain through google as a separate site from `example.com`, but this doesn't seem to buy me anything since I can't see a way to block crawling without using robots.txt - which would block it from the parent domain.

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

Found this conversation on [Webmaster Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/3YkX7MTyc1U)

I am looking into whether it's possible to insert a META tag dynamically into the header of every page called on the static domain using php

**CLARIFICATION**

I am not putting any content on static.domain.com. There are NO webpages on it that are called - it only serves images. I have it redirecting to the same root directory as the main site for ease of coding image links (not every image is fed from the same image path).

Google got a hold of the static web root address - probably because .htaccess redirects to index.php if a file is missing and then crawled it. Now Google is showing the static version of the same pages with search results.

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Steve - I updated the question with a clarification to answer your comment.

Comment: understand what you are doing.  I am just wondering why you are using a subdomain of the primary domain to deliver images.  Why bother?

Comment: @Steve - To be cookieless - by calling a subdomain, every request for an image will not have a cookie sent.

Comment: @steve when we use some third party service like analytics, ads etc in our main website then our static content like images, js also download same cookies in every request. Hence cookieless domain speed up webpage speed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not redirect your user/Googlebot to your main subdomain when your static assets is not found. Instead you should return 404 error. But because you're redirecting them, hence your subdomain is index by Google, so

There is three solution for you.

1. Redirect only your main `static.domain.com` page to `domain.com`, for example facebook redirect their static content cdn domain (fbcdn.net) to facebook.com, so Google will follow the redirection and will drop your subdomain link from search result.
2. Use below robots.txt

`User-Agent: Googlebot
 Allow: .js
 Allow: .css
 Allow: .png
 Allow: .jpg
 Disallow: /`

3. Use [meta noindex tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex) on that webpage.

Make sure the noindex tag only placed on those webpages that you don't want to see on search result, I am telling that, because may be you're using some kind of parent template technique which applied to all child templates.

Another thing is that noindex tag don't stop from crawling, it just used to noindex specific webpage, so that page will not going to appear on Google search result, so if you're using any links on that webpage then Google will still follow all the links and pass it's value just like any normal webpage.

Comment: I am not putting any content on static.domain.com. There are NO webpages on it that are called - it only serves images. Google got a hold of the static web root address - probably because .htaccess redirects to index.php if a file is missing and then crawled it. Now Google is showing the static version of the same pages with search results.

Comment: "I am not putting any content on static.domain.com...it only serves images"  images = content

Comment: I update my answer, based on your comments :)

Comment: Since the robots.txt and .htaccess are shared between the domain an the subdomain (the real problem, I now see), it seems the best solution would be to makes changes in .htaccess to redirect differently based on the domain / subdomain.   Currently, my redirect is simply: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php`
I will have to figure out how to specify the domain in the rewrite condition and rule.

Comment: I am not expert in htaccess so can't add anything on that. Sorry :( But I will say don't use any kind of redirection when resource is not found, let server display the 404 error.